# Javascript or jQuery for taking snapshot of the 1st second of a video file

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Is there any Javascript or jQuery that is able to take a snapshot of the 1st second of a video (can be flv, mpg, mp4 - I am open to any video format) and display in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to look at this:

http://www.webdevhub.net/html-5/video/html5-video-element

It provides a good demo as well as sample of source code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use canvas to display a video so you could take the first frame and show it that way.  But this would only work in the more modern browsers.